# Fatal error in spider catalog extension in joomla 2.5

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, web-crawler, catalog

I am using spider catalog extension to display a catalog of products in my site. After I uploaded my site to the server i was faced with this error when I tried to access the products page:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function phpdefined() in
>   /home/a5401627/public_html/components/com_spidercatalog/spidercatalog.php
>   on line 1

Here is the `spidercatalog.php` file:

```
<?php
defined( '_JEXEC' ) or die( 'Restricted access' );
$document =& JFactory::getDocument();

$document->addStyleSheet(JURI::root(true).'/components/com_spidercatalog/css/spidercatalog_main.css');
$document->addScript(JURI::root(true).'/components/com_spidercatalog/js/common.js');
$document->addScript('components/com_spidercatalog/spiderBox/spiderBox.js.php?delay=3000&allImagesQ=0&slideShowQ=0&darkBG=1&juriroot='.urlencode(JURI::root(false)).'&spiderShop=1');


require_once( JPATH_COMPONENT.DS.'controller.php' );
$controller = JRequest::getVar( 'controller' );

global $param_values;
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
$query ="SELECT *  from #__spidercatalog_params ";

$db->setQuery($query);
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
if ($db->getErrorNum()) {
    echo $db->stderr();
    return false;
}
$param_values=array();

foreach($rows as $row){
$key=$row->name;
$value=$row->value;
$param_values[$key]=$value;
}



class jsshparams{

    function get($key) {
        global $param_values;   
        return $param_values[$key];
    }
}





$classname    = 'spidercatalogController'.$controller;

$controller   = new $classname( );



$controller->execute( JRequest::getVar( 'task' ) );



$controller->redirect();

?>
```

I have tried to look up that error here and online but to no avail and the funny thing is that it works perfectly when i run in in `XAMPP` on my local machine. I would be grateful if you would all help.

EDIT:I have been able to solve the problem by re-installing the extension again.Maybe something got messed up while i was uploading the files to the server

Comment: Have you tried contacting the developers? Whilst you're at it, tell them to update their database queries to Joomla 2.5 coding standards and to remove the `&` symbols as they are deprecated

Comment: @Lodder I have been able to solve the problem by re-installing the extension again.Maybe something got messed up while i was uploading the files to the server.Thank you for your concern and help.